# Iteration for solving $x=g(x)$.

Tags: numerical-methods

$g(x) = \frac{x^2}{3}$

$P=3$

$p_0 = 3.5$

1) Graph $g(x)$, the line $y=x$, and the fixed point $P$ (**done**)

2) Using the given starting value $p_0$, compute $p_1$ and $p_2$
(**the answer might be** $p_1 = 4.083333,p_2 = 5.537869$)

Determine geometrically if fixed point iteration converges (**answer: diverges**)

We might decide this using the analogical graphing structure:

[image]

Please, help!

Comment: It's not at all clear what your question is.

Comment: By the way, I got $p_2=5.557870...$. Looks like you copied a digit wrong.

Comment: I need to know how to get those answers . It has to deal with g'(P) = 2. From figure 2.5 it's monotone divergent as 1< g'(P). But I also need to find $p_1$, $p_2$

It is probably related to the formula $|P-p_n| \le K^n |P-p_0|$.

Comment: the answer says, $p_2 = 5.537869$ However, they are not always exact, so yours is probably correct.

Comment: how did you get 5.557870...?

Comment: Plugged it into a calculator. $p_1=g(p_0)$, $p_2=g(p_1)$....

Comment: BTW the pictures in the post are taken from the book John H. Mathews, Kurtis D. Fink: *Numerical methods using MATLAB*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $g(x)=x\cdot \frac{x}{3}$, we see that if $x>3$ then $g(x)>x$ and if $0\leq x<3$, then $g(x)<x$.  So what we see is that, unless $p_0=3$, $g(p_0),g(g(p_0)),...$ is going to get steadily further away from $3$.

Comment: I am also wondering how you get $p_1$, $p_2$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your graph should look like something like this:

[image]

If $p_0$ is a bit to the right of the fixed point $p=3$, we have $p_1 = g(p_0) > p_0$, so
the iteration takes you farther away from the fixed point, and it diverges.  Similarly
if $p_0$ was a bit to the left of the fixed point $p=3$, you'd have $p_1 = g(p_0) < p_0$.  In that case it would converge to the other other fixed point $0$.